# Inserting into one table and using the id to insert into other table

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am using MySql, and I want to implement a query. 
I have 5 Tables and in MySql they look like this.

```
Table1- Site:
        Site_ID
        domain_name
        site_name

Table2- Locations:
        site_id (Same as from Site)


Table3- Users:
        user_id (AI primary key)
        site_id

Table4- Users_Roles:
        role_id(AI Primary key)
        site_id

Table5- Users_Addresss:
        user_address_id(AI Primary Key)
        user_id (Same as from Users)
        site_id
```

With one single query, I want to insert into all of these tables. My Database is normalized 
I am not able to think of the query that would do the operation.

I will be using this query in a php file and trigger it with the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to insert a record into Site table

```
INSERT INTO Site (domain_name,site_name) VALUES ('www.google.com', 'Test site');
```

Then assign the last insert id i.e. Site_id into a variable like below

```
SET @site_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); // This is the Site_id

INSERT INTO Users (site_id) VALUES (@site_id);
```

Now do the same for all the tables.

Thanks

Comment: And is it not possible to do that into one statement??

Comment: No, as you need the last record id of first insert then you will have to do as above because if we create batch insert statements into one query then last_insert_id() will produce last_insert_id() for each statement.

Comment: And one more query, I will trigger this query with ajax. So multiple statements wouldn't do any harm, right?